# Query on entity with oneToMany relationship return 3 results instead of 1

Tags: jpa-2.0, one-to-many

I have an DecisionEntity that has bidirectional OneToMany relationship to ExplanationEntity. The SpecificDecisionEntity extends DecisionEntity and adds unidirectional manyToOne relationship to the CharacteristicEntity by field other than id. I created the SpecificDecision with one ExplanationEntity linked. But when I tried to select this entity, I got a list with 3 entries of the same entity instead of 1... What is wrong?

CharacteristicEntity:

```
@Entity  
    public class CharacteristicEntity extends BaseEntity {  
    private Long xid;
    public Long getXid() {  
        return xid;  
    }
```

...

ExplanationEntity:

```
@Entity
public class ExplanationEntity extends BaseEntity {  
    ...
    private DecisionEntity decision;

    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.PERSIST}, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, optional=false)
    public DecisionEntity getDecision() {
        return decision;
    }

    public void setDecision(DecisionEntity decision) {
        this.decision = decision;
    }
}
```

DecisionEntity:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="decisionType")
public abstract class DecisionEntity extends BaseEntity {

    private Date date;
    private List<ExplanationEntity> explanations;
    private DefinitionEntity definition;
    private DecisionTypeEnum decisionType;
    private DecisionEntity parent;
    private List<DecisionEntity> subDecisions;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.PERSIST}, mappedBy="hachlata", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    public List<ExplanationEntity> getExplanations() {
        return explanations;
    }

    public void setExplanations(List<ExplanationEntity> explanations) {
        this.explanations = explanations;
    }

    @ManyToOne(optional=false, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    public DefinitionEntity getDefinition() {
        return definition;
    }

    public void setDefinition(DefinitionEntity definition) {
        this.definition = definition;
    }

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    public DecisionTypeEnum getDecisionType() {
        return decisionType;
    }

    public void setDecisionType(DecisionTypeEnum decisionType) {
        this.decisionType = decisionType;
    }

    @ManyToOne(optional=true, cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    public DecisionEntity getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(DecisionEntity parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    public List<DecisionEntity> getSubDecisions() {
        return subDecisions;
    }

    public void setSubDecisions(List<DecisionEntity> subDecisions) {
        this.subDecisions = subDecisions;
    }

}
```

SpecificDecisionEntity:

```
@Entity  
@DiscriminatorValue("specific")  
@NamedQueries({  
    @NamedQuery(name="getSpecificDecisionByCharacteristicId", query="SELECT s FROM SpecificDecisionEntity s WHERE s.characteristic.xid = :xid")  
})  
public class SpecificDecisionEntity extends HachlataEntity {

    private boolean value;
    private CharacteristicEntity characteristic;

    public boolean isValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(boolean value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.REFRESH, optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="xid", nullable=false)
    public CharacteristicEntity getCharacteristic() {
        return characteristic;
    }

    public void setCharacteristic(CharacteristicEntity characteristic) {
        this.characteristic = characteristic;
    }

}
```